# WatchAppでキーボードを数字入力のみにしたい

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $text).keyboardType(.numberPad)
```

iOSの方では上記のコードでキーボードタイプを変更できたのですが、Watch Appではエラーになってしまいます。
どのようにすればキーボードタイプを変更できるのでしょうか？よろしくお願い致します。

Xcode14
Swift5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

情報が古かったら申し訳ありませんが、Appleは公式に`SwiftUI`下で`watchOS`でのデシマルキーボードをサポートしていないようです。
代用として`GitHub`に[SwiftUI Apple Watch Decimal Pad](https://github.com/ApplebaumIan/SwiftUI-Apple-Watch-Decimal-Pad)というライブラリーがあるようです。

Comment: 上記ライブラリーにて、無事実装することが出来ました。